# Bigcommerce API batch update?

Tags: bigcommerce

is there a way to batch update products or orders using bigcommerce api? 
I need to update multiple products with just one call if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the PHP library which can be downloaded @ https://github.com/bigcommerce/auspost-api-php

I first made a local database of products using the following calls...

```
$filter = array('limit' =>, 'page' =>1);
Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter);

foreach($products as $product){
$sku = $product->SKU;
$id = $product->id;
/* write some code in the loop to add all the products to your DB */
}
```

Once you have a DB of all your products you can make SQL call with SELECT ALL from your Database and update them with some static content like below(put below in a loop for each product)....

```
$UpdateQuery = array('description' => 'Some Random Text added to all descriptions')
Bigcommerce::updateProduct($Bicommerce_Product_ID,$UpdateQuery)
```

This would bulk add 'Some Random Text added to all descriptions' too products in your database. You need to use the Bigcommerce product ID in each loop to target it and update in 'bulk'.

Hope this is useful - can verify it works as use it myself :)